# How to iterate over segments and apply style binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have prepared a small demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/chk1vwot/

Basically, I have observable array of sliders, and each slider should have it's own observable array of segments, which contain some properties for CSS-binding in HTML.

I am trying to iterate over all segments and apply style bindings:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: root.segments">
<div class='slider-segment' data-bind= "style: {left: segment_left, 
width: segment_width, backgroundColor: segment_color}"></div>
```

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?
Can i better organize my ViewModel for this?

Comment: Try removing `[` and `]` on this line, since `segments` is already an Array: `self.segments = ko.observableArray([segments]);`

Comment: Tried that, still nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly code foreach and style binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508421/how-to-properly-code-foreach-and-style-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What blex had said was correct. But after that, you also had to give a height to each segment. So I added a height property: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr5z9421/)

HTML:

```
<div class='slider-segment' data-bind= "style: {left: segment_left, 
                                        width: segment_width, 
                                        backgroundColor: segment_color, 
                                        height: segment_height}"></div>
```

JS:

```
segment_array.push({
        segment_left: left,
        segment_width: width,
        segment_color: color,
        segment_height: '10px'
      });
```