# Non-repeated element inside KnockoutJS foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to create a knockout.js component (with CSS3 grids) that displays a bunch of sub-components, which I know can be done via something like:

```html
<div class="items grid" data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
    <item-component params="data: item" class="grid-item"></item-component>
</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to put a non-repeated item into this list. Ultimately, I want to generate something along these lines:

```html
<div class="items grid">
    <div class="something-else grid-item"></div>
    <item-component class="grid-item"></item-component>
    <item-component class="grid-item"></item-component>
    <item-component class="grid-item"></item-component>
</div>
```

The reason I can't just put the `something-else` outside of the `foreach`-bound element is that it's also a grid item, so it has to be a direct child of the grid. It crossed my mind to manually append it via jquery's `append`, but with MVVM, that's a terrible idea (it doesn't work anyway).

Does anyone know a way to do this with knockout.js?

Comment: In Angular, when a "foreach" is used, it repeats that specific line, which would be the normal way of solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, it looks you need [containerless control flow](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-and-ifnot-without-a-container-element). It has been talked about in the 2nd point of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518320/5488850).

It allows you to do things like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Header item</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
        <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li class="tail">Tail item</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Header item</li>
    <li>Item <span>Spoon</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>Fork</span></li>
    <li class="tail">Tail item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for providing the technical name, `containerless control flow`, as well.